# Excel VBA copying From one worksheet to another row by row up to a fixed number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy row 2 of a worksheet (Import Setup) to row 2 of another worksheet (Import) Then I need to copy columns L-O on the next row of the import setup worksheet and append it to the end of row 2 in on the Import worksheet is the amount in column L is greater than 0.  I need to continue copying columns L-O from the next rows on Import Setup sheet into the import sheet until I copy 98 rows, then I need to copy the entire row of the following row on the Import Setup sheet to row 3 of the Import sheet and continue as above until I reach 98 then repeat process again.  I know what I have here will work but I am looking for an easier way then having to type out so much code.

```
Sub Create_invoice()

' Copies the first row of an invoice to the import template

    Sheets("Import Setup").Select
    Range("A2:O2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Import").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Calls macro to copy additional Distributions up to 99

Call Copy_Distribution

End Sub

Sub Copy_Distribution()

'Copys distribution if invoice amount is not 0 up to 99

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L3").Value > 0 Then
  Range("L3:O3").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("P2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L4").Value > 0 Then
 Range("L4:O4").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("T2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L5").Value > 0 Then
 Range("L5:O5").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("X2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L6").Value > 0 Then
 Range("L6:O6").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("AB2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L7").Value > 0 Then
 Range("L7:O7").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("AF2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L8").Value > 0 Then
 Range("L8:O8").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("AJ2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L9").Value > 0 Then
 Range("L9:O9").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("AN2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L10").Value > 0 Then
 Range("L10:O10").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("AR2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L11").Value > 0 Then
 Range("L11:O11").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("AV2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L12").Value > 0 Then
 Range("L12:O12").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("AZ2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If

 Sheets("Import Setup").Select
 If Range("L13").Value > 0 Then
 Range("L13:O13").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Import").Select
 Range("BD2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Wait, you say your code works but you want it shorter?

Comment: Ohhh, I see what you are doing. This is highly inefficient. It will work but there is a better way. You need to use `For Loops`.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with loops

```
Sub Copy_Distribution()
Dim OriginSheet As Worksheet
Set OriginSheet = Sheets("Import Setup")
Dim ObjectiveSheet As Worksheet
Set ObjectiveSheet = Sheets("Import")
Dim ColumnToPaste As Long
Dim RowToGetValue As Long
Dim GetColumn As Long
ColumnToPaste = 15 'Because GetColumn
For RowToGetValue = 3 To 98 'From 3 to 98 right?
    If OriginSheet.Cells(RowToGetValue, 12).Value > 0 Then
        For GetColumn = 1 To 4
            ObjectiveSheet.Cells(2, ColumnToPaste + GetColumn).Value = OriginSheet.Cells(RowToGetValue, 11 + GetColumn).Value
        Next GetColumn
    ColumnToPaste = ColumnToPaste + 4
    End If
Next RowToGetValue

End Sub
```

I replaced the ranges to be dynamic, from row 3 to 98, and made the columns get increments of 4, so they wont overlap.
Can you give it a try to see if it works with your data?

Comment: I works but it is only copying the information from column L not columns L through O from the original worksheet. It also doesn't seem to be copying 98 lines of data

Comment: I think now its fixed. I'm not used to ranges, so I reverted back to cells, so now I know it works. However, it goes from line 3 to line 98. It should go to line 101? You can see where to change that, right?

Comment: That worked.  I tried to setup a second sub called copy distribution2 and called it at the end to enter the lines for the second invoice distribution but it doesn't seem to work, it sums them up (I added that to the end of the first sub) but it doesn't insert the rows like the first one does

Comment: Figured it out I had to change it to row 3 was overwriting row 2